# Which items are considered battering items?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Them item **Item Hitter Helmet** (equip-able to Mega Man) states

> 1.5x attack power to battering items.

Which items are considered *battering items*?

No speculation please. I'm looking for either a way to find indications of item type in-game, or an analytical answer.

Comment: http://www.ssbwiki.com/Item ?

Comment: Hmm didn't find that when I searched! My Google-fu failed... Perhaps turn it into an answer?

Comment: Each item's type is listed in-game when you select it in the item switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look it up at the items on the [ssbwiki](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Item):

- Beam Sword
- Fire bar
- Home-run bat
- Lip's stick
- Ore club
- Star rod
- Hammer
- Golden Hammer

This information may also be found *in game*. Once Item Switch has been unlocked in the Rules menu, you can check the lower screen for information on the current item you have selected on the top. The item's type is shown, highlighted in orange, next to the item's name.

Comment: The Fan and Parasol aren't available in this game.

Comment: I also added Hammer and Golden Hammer to your list, since the item switch in-game lists them as battering items.

Comment: Edited (pending review) to include info on finding this in-game.

Comment: @Jason_c_o yes, I saw and approved. Thanks for the clarification!